# Перевод из двоичного формата в текстовый java

Tags: java, c#

Есть код на с# пытаюсь переписать на java,но не понимаю где смысл,в общем передается в качестве string бинарный код,который переводится в текстовый формат.
Сам код

```
private string StringFromBinaryToNormalFormat(string input)
{
    string output = "";

    while (input.Length > 0)
    {
        string char_binary = input.Substring(0, sizeOfChar);//тут просто input это 128 символьная строка из 0 и 1 и в char_binary "вырезаем" 16 символов,которые и надо перевести в какое то текстовое представление  
        input = input.Remove(0, sizeOfChar);

        int a = 0;
        int degree = char_binary.Length - 1;

        foreach (char c in char_binary)
            a += Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString()) * (int)Math.Pow(2, degree--);

        output += ((char)a).ToString();
    }

    return output;
}
```

ну во первых,не понимаю почему тут бесконечный цикл

```
while (input.Length > 0)
```

во вторых,сам перевод в текстовый формат,как я понял,мы представляем `string` как массив,конвертируем из `char` в `int`овое представление и умножаем на 2 в какой  о степени,на выходе просто большие числа,какая связь с символами?
Понимаю,что вопрос может местами неуместный,может есть какая то другая реализация перевода из бинарного в текстовый?
**UPD** :в общем разобрался что тут происходит,теперь другая проблема есть десятичное представление 59335,как это выглядит в unicodе?похоже такого символа нету..

Comment: Заголовок вопроса должен отражать смысл задачи, проблему. Другим потом легче ответ искать

Comment: просто загуглить "Unicode 59335" обычно используется 16ричная СС "U+E7C7", например:

Unicode number U+E7C7
HTML-code &#59335;
( https://unicode-table.com/en/E7C7/ )

Comment: @Alias просто выводит знаки вопроса,вместо каких либо символов

Comment: @Аркадий,  возможно дело в том, что этот символ из "Private Use Areas (PUA)" (U+E000 – U+F8FF) нестандартный, консоль C# не умеет его отображать -- попробуй писать в файл (используя 2х-байтовую кодировку вывода, не ASCII/ANSI по умолчанию).

Comment: @Alias пишу на java,дело в том что любой символ,например,латиницы выводит как знак вопроса,не только E7C7,пишу System.out.println("\u010D"); вместо греч. С опять таки знак вопроса,компилирую все в консоли,уже не знаю что делать

Comment: @Аркадий, не понял, почему взяли для примера **греческую** С?
16ричный код символа 'С': для англ. 0063, русск. 0441.
Никогда не писал на Java  :-|  возможно, не совпадает кодировка (CP866(DOS), CP1251(Windows)), или ожидаемый порядок байт(UTF-16BE | LE).
В приведённом коде переменная sizeOfChar нигде не определена,
 может это UTF-8 -- просто в C# тип char двухбайтовый, но в него и значение менее можно записать.

Comment: @Аркадий мне кажется, что используемый диапазон наверняка поменьше (нафиг кому-то греческие символы или символы с умляутами) -- попробуйте при разборе строки входной двоичной записи взять размер символа sizeOfChar=8.

Answer (score 1):

> почему тут бесконечный цикл

Цикл тут не бесконечный. Обратите внимание на

```
input = input.Remove(0, sizeOfChar);
```

Это показывает, что строка каждый раз уменьшается, пока не станет равной 0.

> сам перевод в текстовый формат,как я понял,мы представляем string как
>   массив,конвертируем из char в intовое представление и умножаем на 2 в
>   какой о степени,на выходе просто большие числа,какая связь с символами

Ну тут тоже понятно, строка видимо записывается как

```
010010101001
```

где `010010` - первый символ, `101001` - второй символ и т.д.

Как из нулей и единиц получить символ, скажем, А - правильно нужно по правилам битовой арифметики записать число А, поэтому строка `010010` превратиться в (0 * 32) + (1 * 16) + (0 * 8) + (0 * 4) + (1 * 2) + (0 * 1) = 18. Это будет некоторым кодом символа в десятичной системе.

> Понимаю,что вопрос может местами неуместный,может есть какая то другая
>   реализация перевода из бинарного в текстовый?

Конечно, смотрите сериализацию или представления строки Java в виде массива байт. Но тут скорее всего производится еще и сжатие символов (например, если точно известно что возможны символы только английского алфавита, то для кодирования будет достаточно меньшего кол-ва бит).

Comment: хотел добавить что, что есть исходный текст,длина которого =4,он специально  доводится до длины= 8,путем добавления любого символа,длина строки input которая передается в качестве аргумента 128 бит,размер char в unicod 16 бит,тут и получаем,что 128/16=8 тех самых начальных символов,хочу сказать что как раз 1 символ это 16 наборов 0  и 1,если я все правильно понимаю